# Correlate 3 vectors that are sampled from 3 different distributions

Tags: distributions, correlation, sampling, matlab

I have three vectors with sampled values in MATLAB, each from a specific probability distribution. (The vectors contain time series data of the growth rate of retail prices of specific goods)

```
%pearsrnd(mu,sigma,skew,kurt,m,n)
commodity1=pearsrnd(0.005,0.085,0.237,7.899,1,600);
commodity2=pearsrnd(0.003,0.040,0.280,5.630,1,600);
commodity3=pearsrnd(0.006,0.139,-0.207,4.209,1,600);
```

However, I want to add two correlation to the data. Specifically, the correlation between commodity 1 and commodity 3 should be 0.135, the correlation between commodity 2 and 3 should be 0.115. How can I solve this most easily?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for exact (non-random) correlation, you can remove the sample correlation from the data you have, then impose the correlation you want. Here's a way to do that in MATLAB using Cholesky factors of the sample and desired correlation matrices:

```
>> x = randn(100,3);
>> Sigma0 = cov(x);
>> Sigma1 = [1 0 .135; 0 1 .115; .135 .115 1];
>> z = (x/chol(Sigma0))*chol(Sigma1);
>> cov(z)
ans =
    1.0000    0.0000    0.1350
    0.0000    1.0000    0.1150
    0.1350    0.1150    1.0000
```

Ordinarily, though, I would want to specify the desired correlation for the population, and let the sample correlation vary. That's relatively simple to do for rank correlations using copulas.

Comment: Won't this alter the shapes of the marginal distributions?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use copulas? I've checked the documentation, but it seems that the correlated vectors are drawn from a uniform(0,1) distribution. I don't see how that would work with the distributions I specified earlier.

Comment: It's right that this will alter the marginal distributions.

Comment: Okay, my answer may turn out not to be helpful. It's also right that the copula produces uniform values. The idea is that you apply the inverse cdf function to those in each dimension. This transformation does not change the rank correlation. However, there's no built-in MATLAB function to compute the inverse for the Pearson distribution. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Is is possible to use copulas by sorting a random sample instead of using the inverse cdf. This will allow you to impose a correlation on the population, but the sample correlation will still have some random variation around the specified value. Here's how.

Generate independent random samples:

```
N = 60000;
commodity1=pearsrnd(0.005,0.085,0.237,7.899,1,N)';
commodity2=pearsrnd(0.003,0.040,0.280,5.630,1,N)';
commodity3=pearsrnd(0.006,0.139,-0.207,4.209,1,N)';
```

Create a copula with the desired correlation. Note that R below is the correlation matrix for the multivariate normal distribution on which the copula is based. It is not the correlation of the copula itself, nor it is the rank correlation.

```
R = [1 .135 .115; .135 1 -.1; .115 -.1 1];
U = copularnd('gaussian',R,N);
copula_rankcorr = corr(U,'type','spearman')
copula_rankcorr =
    1.0000    0.1289    0.1054
    0.1289    1.0000   -0.0960
    0.1054   -0.0960    1.0000
```

Force the data to have the same rank correlation as the copula.

```
[~,J] = sort(U);
Y = zeros(size(U));
Y(J(:,1),1) = sort(commodity1);
Y(J(:,2),2) = sort(commodity2);
Y(J(:,3),3) = sort(commodity3);
imposed_rankcorr = corr(Y,'type','spearman')
imposed_rankcorr =
    1.0000    0.1289    0.1054
    0.1289    1.0000   -0.0960
    0.1054   -0.0960    1.0000
pearson_corr = corr(Y)
pearson_corr =
    1.0000    0.1324    0.1074
    0.1324    1.0000   -0.1006
    0.1074   -0.1006    1.0000
```